# How to know where a docker image came from?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image on my system `12346789ABCD`.

Is there a way to know where it is coming from?

Specifically, I would like to know if it was built locally or downloaded from a repository, and in that latter case, downloaded from which repository.

Comment: Hi, not an answer but  maybe first hint - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769315/how-to-see-docker-image-contents

Comment: Also: https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I've already investigated `docker inspect`: `docker inspect -f '{{json .}}' debian | jq '{RepoTags,RepoDigests}'` The presence of RepoTags and RepoDigest is a clue the image was downloaded. But I can't see from where.

Comment: Consider starting a container to explore contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, if it's from a registry, you see that in the name of the image (if it's not from the default registry, Docker Hub). Images from Quay look like `quay.io/<namespace>/<image name>:<tag>`.

Some images are from *from* anywhere else at all. For example images that are `FROM: scratch` and images created via `docker import` will not be associated with any registry. These are the famous `none:none` images (no repository and no tag). In this case, you only have the ID (SHA) and you need do be Sherlock Holmes (or Jessie Frazelle) to match it with something.

So, you can only see what is written in the manifest. Should you trust it? The manifest can be signed, using [docker content trust](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/) even if the image contents themselves are not.  If you need more certainty on the provenance, you probably need [notary](https://github.com/theupdateframework/notary)  to ensure that trust is maintained throughout the delegation chain.

Hope that answers the question.